# Having trouble with a 'while' loop in C++

Tags: c++, while-loop

I started building a very simple version of a calculator in C++. The idea is to perform basic operations with only two numbers and then loop back so the user can make a new calculation.

The program looks like this:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include"mathOperations.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  int x, y;
  string operation;
  string repeat = "y";

  while (repeat == "y" or "Y")
  {
    cout << "Welcome! This is a raw version of a calculator - only use two numbers." << endl;
    cin >> x >> operation >> y;

    if (operation == "+")
    {
      cout << "Result: " << add(x, y) << endl;
    }
    else if (operation == "-")
    {
      cout << "Result: " << subtract(x, y) << endl;
    }
    else if (operation == "*")
    {
      cout << "Result: " << multiply(x, y) << endl;
    }
    else if (operation == "/")
    {
      cout << "Result: " << divide(x, y) << endl;
    }
    else
    {
      cout << "This is not a valid sign. Please choose another one!" << endl;
    }

    cout << "Wanna go again? Type 'y' or 'n'." << endl;
    cin >> repeat;

    if (repeat == "n" or "N")
    {
      cout << "Alright, have a nice day!" << endl;
      break;
    }
  }
}

int add(int x, int y)
{
  return x + y;
}

int subtract(int x, int y)
{
  return x - y;
}

int multiply(int x, int y)
{
  return x * y;
}

int divide(int x, int y)
{
  return x / y;
}
```

**NOTE:** There is a 'mathOperations.h' file in which I have made forward declarations of all functions used.

The problem is that whenever I type in 'y' to make it loop, it simply outputs the following 'if' statement and breaks out of the loop and the program finishes. I couldn't quite figure out why this is happening, since the 'if' statement is only supposed to run if I type in 'n'.

Comment: `or` doesn't give a selection of possible values, it is a combination of boolean expressions

Comment: if (repeat == "n" or repeat == "N"). Same with y

Comment: @JesperJuhl  How do you know the OP isn't *working* from a book?  If questions like this don't represent the reason for this site, what is?  Comments like this drive away the very people who need this site.  Please comment/answer when you have something constructive to say.

Comment: I know it's a style preference, but you can also half the number of lines you have by losing the excess {} for all the if / else statements.

Comment: @UKMonkey Your comment will stir a discussion almost as intense as the vim/emacs battle :)

Comment: @vsoftco to which the answer is of course, notepad ^_^

Comment: *while (repeat == "y" or "Y")* -- Unfortunately, `if` statements in C++ do not follow the way we speak shorthand English.  If you want to compare multiple things, you have to specify the entire statement each time, e.g. `if (x == y or x == z)` instead of `if (x == y or z)`

Comment: @DaveSwersky I appreciate your comment. I really do feel annoyed when I see a question (especially my own) get instantly downvoted because of people who think like this because the question isn't good enough for them...

Comment: I actually think this is a perfectly good question - it's well formed, the question is clear, the code is included (although not minimal; but pretty small)... it satisfies all the requirements for a question here.

Comment: @Brunky: For future reference, you should have removed the '*' and '/' cases, and the corresponding functions.  Discovering that you could remove the '-' case too would have been more work - but useful.  It really is worth spending some time to prepare a minimal example.  (But thanks for giving us code which isn't *too* huge).

Comment: @MartinBonner I'll keep this in mind, thanks for the advice

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
repeat == "n" or "N"
```

evaluates to

```
(repeat == "n") || "N"
```

see the [C++ operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence).

The first `repeat == "n"` evaluates to `true` or `false` depending on your input, but the second clause of the OR, i.e. `"N"`, always evaluates to `true` because it is a string literal that decays to a non-zero `const char*` pointer, and in C or C++ everything non-zero is implicitly converted to `true`. So your OR clause is always `true`, which implies that the `if` block will always be executed.

As mentioned in the comments, you need to do

```
if(repeat == "n" || repeat == "N") {...}
```

Similarly with the first `while` condition.

Answer (score 1):

Nice code! I try using "||" in place of your "or" in your if statements. Might want to refresh your knowledge with C++ short-circuiting of booleans.